# Advantages to two modules with same interface or two classes with the same interface?

Tags: python, oop, module, ooad

For example I can create two modules (`Mod1` and `Mod2`) that have `f()`.  Or I can create two classes that implement `f()`.

I can then either

```
if condition:
    import Mod1 as m
else:
    import Mod2 as m

m.f()
```

or

```
if condition:
    m = Class1()
else:
    m = Class2()
m.f()
```

Obviously if I want to store any state I need to use classes, but if I am just using class methods, are there advantages to either method over the other?

**EDIT:** I am mostly concerned with maintainability/extensibility/readability and not with runtime performance.

Comment: i think this would depend on how often/what you are using f() for

Comment: In this specific case, I will probably be calling each method just once, but I'm also curious about a general case.

Comment: i think generally, you would create the modules, not the class just because a class is normally associated with creating object instances with attributes,class methods, etc rather than just for functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## General Idea

In your specific case, you could go with simple module level function, not to overcomplicate everything. But as far as you are interested in the general case, I would recommend you to go with the [Abstract Factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern). Here is an example solution for you:

```
class YourAbstractFactory(object):
    @classmethod
    def get_factory(cls, condition):
        cond_map = {
            'impl1': Impl1,
            'impl2': Impl2
        }

        impl = cond_map.get(condition)

        return impl() if impl else None

    def f1(self):
        pass

    def f2(self):
        pass
```

`YourAbstractFacotry` class is obviously an abstract class, that simply defines the interface to be implemented, i.e. the collection of your `f` functions. Moreover it defines and implements the `get_factory` class method that returns the appropriate implementation, depending on the condition.

```
class Impl1(YourAbstractFactory):
    def f1(self):
        print('Impl1.f1')

    def f2(self):
        print('Impl1.f2')

class Impl2(YourAbstractFactory):
    def f1(self):
        print('Impl2.f1')

    def f2(self):
        print('Impl2.f2')
```

The above classes are the two independent implementations of your interface. The are unaware of each other and can exist independently.

```
# This is where you put your condition, and get appropriate instance
>>> impl = YourAbstractFactory.get_factory('impl2')
>>> impl.f1()
Impl2.f1
```

So the advantage of this solution in general case is that your client code will be decoupled of you implementations. Meaning, that you will only pass the condition and get the required implementation, and have no any idea and dependency on that implementation inside you client code. The only piece that is aware of the concrete implementations of the interface is the `get_factory` method, which is easy to maintain.

## Additional Improvements

To further enhance this solution and increase the security (although, Python is a language for adults ;) ), you can also use the [`abc`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html) module, with its [`ABCMeta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta) metaclass and [`abstractmethod`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod) decorator, to prevent initialising instances of classes that do not implement all the interface. In this case you will need to define your factory class like this.

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class YourAbstractFactory(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @classmethod
    def get_factory(cls, condition):
        cond_map = {
            'impl1': Impl1,
            'impl2': Impl2
        }

        impl = cond_map.get(condition)

        return impl() if impl else None

    @abstractmethod
    def f1(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def f2(self):
        pass
```